# Change search engine of Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, search-engine

I need to change Search Engine of Visual Studio 2019.

**Bing** is not suitable for me.

I prefer **Google** to **Bing**.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find this option:
Go to **Tool** -> **Option** -> **Text Editor** -> **C++** -> **Advanced** -> **Search Provider** -> change **bing** to **google**.
That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Go to: **Tools** -> **Option** -> **Text Editor** -> **C/C++** -> **Advanced** -> **IntelliSense** -> **Search Provider** -> then change "bing" to "google".